# Build time error HookWebpackError: [object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin. This happened when i updated next.js to latest version

Tags: reactjs, build, next.js, postcss

I was using CSS in the next.js using ziet/next CSS module. Today I upgraded the next.js to the latest version and removed this ziet package because next.js now has its own CSS support. The app runs perfectly on the development. But when I tried to build it on production it shows me this error. I never used postCSS in my app but still, it is showing me this error. The below shown is my next.config.js and I have no plugin.json file. I think there is some update so I got this error. Please, someone, explain to me how to fix this error.
**next.config.js**

```
module.exports={
    publicRuntimeConfig:{
        APP_NAME:'my app name',
        API_DEVELOPMENT:'localhost',
        API_PRODUCTION:'domain name',
        PRODUCTION:false,
        DOMAIN_DEVELOPMENT:'localhost',
        DOMAIN_PRODUCTION:'my domain',
        FB_APP_ID:'some id',
        DISQUS_SHORTNAME:'some string',
        GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID:'some string'

    },
    future: {
        webpack5: true,
      },
     
}
```

Comment: From what version did you upgrade Next.js from? If you remove `webpack5` future flag, do you still get the same error?

Comment: OK, I think I got the problem but I don't know its solution. I used the API folder inside pages to generate a sitemap. Now what script should I write in the next.config.js to build this page.

Comment: FYI I had the same issue, downgraded to next@10.1.3 and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error when upgrading from Next.js 10 to 11 and trying to build my project.

I was able to solve it by:

- removing `@zeit/next-sass` from the dependencies in `package.json`
- deleting `package-lock.json`, `node_modules` and `build`
- running `npm install` and `npm run build` again.

(Not sure you need to delete those files/directories but I had too since I had other errors after I resolved this one.)

Answer (score 1):

`npm install postcss@8` and make sure you have successfully installed the `postcss: ^8.x.x` as upgrading `next` doesn't necessarily update the peer dependencies (which `postcss` is) and `You must install peer dependencies yourself.` It fixes the issue.